# PHP - include file with specific id

Tags: php, mysql, database, plugins, content-management-system

I have made a custom cms system that works with 'shortcodes'. With some help i came this far, but am stuck on the part to make the shortcode for a specific ID. Can someone point me in the right direction or explain me how to do this?

This is what i got:

```
/*
example of content stored in database:

$content = "These are my clothes in a slider [plugin-slider] , and these are my shoes [plugin-slider]";

what i would like to to:

$content = "These are my clothes in a slider [plugin-slider id=3] , and these are my shoes [plugin-slider id=5]";

or even better:

$content = "These are my clothes in a slider [plugin-slider name=clothes] , and these are my shoes [plugin-slider name=shoes]";
*/

<?php
    $regex = '~\[plugin-([^]]+)]~';
    $content = htmlspecialchars_decode($page['content']);//content from db
    $parts = preg_split($regex, $content, -1, PREG_SPLIT_DELIM_CAPTURE); //get shortcodes

    foreach($parts as $k => $v){
        if($k & 1)
            include_once('plugins/'.$v.'.php'); //include shortcodes
        else
            echo htmlspecialchars_decode($v); //rest of content
    }
?>
```

Now lets say i have a plugin slider, and made one for a specific page, but i want to use another slider from the same plugin for another page. Can I include them by ID? like [plugin-slider id=26]?

I am almost sure i need to edit the plugins as well, but i have no clue where to start. All help is appreciated!

Comment: What's your files name. Like plugin-slide.php or ? And please add your complete code

Comment: The file is named slide.php yes. The rest of the code is nothing more than the database connection, and the query to get the $page['content'].

Comment: Please write me 2 or 3 example page name stored in database. and why you are using regex

Comment: Of course! Forgot that was a usefull part for this problem. I am using regex to check where i call my plugins. Right now i use it to change [plugin-blog] to include_once('plugins/blog.php');

Comment: Did i ask something extremely hard? ^^